# Fiddler/Jscript.NET :How do I append a string to specific search query?

Tags: append, fiddler, jscript.net

The problem with the below code is that it appends string at the very end of the URL

```
if (oSession.uriContains("search?q=")) 
    {
        var str = oSession.fullUrl;
        var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
        if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
        {
            oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
        }
    }
```

So, How can I conditionally place `+test1+test2+test3` right next to `search?q=` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem with replace function:

```
if (oSession.uriContains("search?q=")) 
    {
        var str = oSession.fullUrl;
        var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
        if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
        {
            oSession.fullUrl = str.replace( "search?q=","search?q="+sAppend);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, when I keep issuing the request it keeps appending over and over again, http://imgur.com/nKCvgKn. This only happens to google.

Comment: @jaridwilders Is this if part of any kind of loop? You can also add one more condition that checks if the URL already contains `sAppend ` string

Comment: Can you please give me an example?, I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: @jaridwilders - `if (oSession.uriContains("search?q=") && !oSession.uriContains(sAppend))` - but you must define `sAppend` outside of the if statement.

Comment: I was able to partially solve the problem, If you type from main google page, Google does not start with `search?q=`, it starts with `search?site=&source=hp&q=&oq=`. How do I solve that?

Comment: @jaridwilders - as I understand you want to make this a google search query?

Comment: @jaridwilders - what if you search for `"&q="` and replace it with `"&q=+test1+test2+test3"`

Comment: `"&q=+test1+test2+test3"`Does not work. Anyway, can you please review this code  `oSession.fullUrl = oSession.fullUrl.Substring( 0,oSession.fullUrl.IndexOf("search?q=")) + sAppend ;`

Comment: Wait!!.... I take that back, &q=+test1+test2+test3 does work,but when I click Next page in google. It browser freezes completetly. Any ideas?

Comment: what browser you use? try with the debuging tools...Chrome and Firefox have the best toolsets for developers

Comment: Google instant search was the one freezing the broswer, solved the problem by disabling it in the search settings. Thank you  for the help.